# How to both postgresql server syncing?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization

I hope to know how I can both postgresql syncing?

A and B server, and B server want  A server's changing datas.

In other words, I want to import the changed data of psql  automatic whenever I want.

How I do it?

Comment: Googling [`Replication`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) ?

Comment: You want to "magically merge" the changes made on two database servers? That will result in replication conflicts unless the application is specially designed to support such a scenario. Think harder and specify your exact requirements. Multi-master replication is probably not the solution.

Comment: @dwir182  Thank you . I uploaded new post.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thank you sir